why the code stop and i cant input any thing after selecting the sub-choice?
so the issue is that after i select the sub-choice, it only says enter category for example to search but i cant write any thing there.
**here is the server code:
**
import socket

print("THE SERVER LOOP HAS STARTED")

soc_b = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
address = ("127.0.0.1", 49987)

soc_b.bind(address)

soc_b.listen(2)
print("Server is listening for incoming connections...")

while True:
    soc_a, socname = soc_b.accept()
    print("Client connected:", socname)

    client_name = soc_a.recv(1024).decode()  # Receive client's name
    print("Client's name:", client_name)

    while True:
        # Send main menu options to the client
        menu_options = "Main Menu\n1. Search headlines\n2. List of Sources\n3. Quit\n"
        soc_a.sendall(menu_options.encode())

        data = soc_a.recv(1024).decode()

        if not data:
            print("Client disconnected")
            break

        # Main menu
        if data == "1":
            # Send headlines menu options to the client
            headlines_menu = "Headlines Menu\n1. Search for keywords\n2. Search by category\n3. Search by country\n4. List all new headlines\n5. Back to the main menu\n"
            soc_a.sendall(headlines_menu.encode())
            option_choice = soc_a.recv(1024).decode()

            if option_choice == "1":
                # Logic for "Search for keywords" option
                soc_a.sendall("Enter keywords to search:".encode())
                keywords = ""
                while True:
                    chunk = soc_a.recv(1024).decode()
                    keywords += chunk
                    if len(chunk) < 1024:
                        break
                response = f"Search headlines by keywords: {keywords}"
                soc_a.sendall(response.encode())
            elif option_choice == "2":
                # Logic for "Search by category" option
                soc_a.sendall("Enter category to search:".encode())
                category = ""
                while True:
                    chunk = soc_a.recv(1024).decode()
                    category += chunk
                    if len(chunk) < 1024:
                        break
                response = f"Search headlines by category: {category}"
                soc_a.sendall(response.encode())
            elif option_choice == "3":
                # Logic for "Search by country" option
                soc_a.sendall("Enter country to search:".encode())
                country = ""
                while True:
                    chunk = soc_a.recv(1024).decode()
                    country += chunk
                    if len(chunk) < 1024:
                        break
                response = f"Search headlines by country: {country}"
                soc_a.sendall(response.encode())
            elif option_choice == "4":
                # Logic for "List all new headlines" option
                response = "List all new headlines"
                soc_a.sendall(response.encode())
            elif option_choice == "5":
                # Logic for "Back to the main menu" option
                continue
            else:
                soc_a.sendall("Invalid command. Please try again.".encode())

        elif data == "2":
            # Send sources menu options to the client
            sources_menu = "Sources Menu\n1. Search by category\n2. Search by country\n3. Search by language\n4. List all\n5. Back to the main menu\n"
            soc_a.sendall(sources_menu.encode())
            option_choice = soc_a.recv(1024).decode()

            if option_choice == "1":
                # Logic for "Search by category" option
                soc_a.sendall("Enter category to search:".encode())
                category = ""
                while True:
                    chunk = soc_a.recv(1024).decode()
                    category += chunk
                    if len(chunk) < 1024:
                        break
                response = f"Search sources by category: {category}"
                soc_a.sendall(response.encode())
            elif option_choice == "2":
                # Logic for "Search by country" option
                soc_a.sendall("Enter country to search:".encode())
                country = ""
                while True:
                    chunk = soc_a.recv(1024).decode()
                    country += chunk
                    if len(chunk) < 1024:
                        break
                response = f"Search sources by country: {country}"
                soc_a.sendall(response.encode())
            elif option_choice == "3":
                # Logic for "Search by language" option
                soc_a.sendall("Enter language to search:".encode())
                language = ""
                while True:
                    chunk = soc_a.recv(1024).decode()
                    language += chunk
                    if len(chunk) < 1024:
                        break
                response = f"Search sources by language: {language}"
                soc_a.sendall(response.encode())
            elif option_choice == "4":
                # Logic for "List all" option
                response = "List all sources"
                soc_a.sendall(response.encode())
            elif option_choice == "5":
                # Logic for "Back to the main menu" option
                continue
            else:
                soc_a.sendall("Invalid command. Please try again.".encode())

        elif data == "3":
            response = "Quitting the program. Goodbye!"
            soc_a.sendall(response.encode())
            soc_a.close()
            break

        else:
            soc_a.sendall("Invalid command. Please try again.".encode())

    soc_a.close()

soc_b.close()

**and here is the client code:
**
import socket

soc_a = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
address = ("127.0.0.1", 49987)

try:
    soc_a.connect(address)
    print("Connected to the server.")

    # Send client's username to identify itself
    client_name = input("Enter your username: ")
    soc_a.sendall(client_name.encode())

    while True:
        # Receive and display the current menu
        menu_options = soc_a.recv(4096).decode()
        print(menu_options)

        option = input("Enter your choice: ").strip()  # Remove leading/trailing whitespace
        soc_a.sendall(option.encode())

        if option == "3" or "quit" in option.lower():
            print("Quitting...")
            break

        # Receive and display the response based on the selected option
        response = soc_a.recv(4096).decode()
        print("Server says:")
        print(response)

        # Check if the response indicates a return to the main menu
        if "returning to the main menu" in response.lower():
            continue

        # Receive and process user input for sub-menu options
        sub_option = input("Enter your sub-choice: ").strip()  # Remove leading/trailing whitespace
        soc_a.sendall(sub_option.encode())

        # Receive and display the response based on the sub-option
        sub_response = soc_a.recv(4096).decode()
        print("Server says:")
        print(sub_response)
   
except ConnectionRefusedError:
    print("The server is not running or is unavailable.")

finally:
    soc_a.close()

so the system will later retrive the news based on the selected option. but for now i want to be able to specify waht i want to search for.

Read the Socket Programming HOWTO.  TCP is a byte streaming protocol not a message-based one.  One send does not equal one recv.
